# .Round() method does not work with my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 created with data imported from excel as shown below and I wish to round down the columns from 'Unnamed 26' to 'Unnamed 34' to 3 decimal places.

Input:df1

```
     Curve 7  Unnamed: 26  Unnamed: 27 Unnamed: 30  Unnamed: 31  Unnamed: 34  
126  2424.53 -0.000416507  0.000547765  0.00123807  0.000496849  0.000611638   
127  2414.78 -0.000524779  0.000573377  0.00144546  0.000465293  0.000653559   
128  2400.96 -0.000522968  0.000775356  0.00192514  0.000654915  0.000874891   
129  2385.15 -0.000660529  0.000800742  0.00254473  0.000915885   0.00121266   
130  2369.16 -0.000633806  0.000877753  0.00292714   0.00121839   0.00156733   
..       ...          ...          ...         ...          ...          ...   
230  863.956   0.00732472 -0.000931889   0.0248365  0.000417123    0.0198425   
231  849.027   0.00743242 -0.000944736   0.0255833  0.000450288    0.0204515   
232  833.801   0.00761184 -0.000993092   0.0265546  0.000394343    0.0211056   
233   818.99   0.00778416 -0.000939103   0.0275128  0.000466737    0.0216808   
234  804.799   0.00780258 -0.000769448   0.0278843  0.000755645    0.0217333
```

**df1.info()**

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 109 entries, 126 to 234
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------       --------------  ----- 
 0   Curve 7      109 non-null    object
 1   Unnamed: 26  109 non-null    object
 2   Unnamed: 27  109 non-null    object
 3   Unnamed: 30  109 non-null    object
 4   Unnamed: 31  109 non-null    object
 5   Unnamed: 34  109 non-null    object
 6   Unnamed: 35  109 non-null    object
dtypes: object(7)
memory usage: 6.1+ KB
```

**Attempt 1:**
`df2=df1.round(3)`

**Output:**
df2 remains the same as df1.

**Attempt2:** specifically call in the columns to be rounded down via

`list=['Unnamed: 26','Unnamed: 27','Unnamed: 30','Unnamed: 31','Unnamed: 34','Unnamed: 35']`
`df2=pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=list)`

**Output:**
df2 remains the same as df1.

Not sure what else to try...?

Comment: I ran your code in my environment. It is correctly rounded to three digits. Check the data type with `df.info()`.

Comment: I have updated my original post. This info would suggest that the dataframe has non-null entries and thus should work? I will look at @Clinton Sorrel's post too

Comment: Since the data type must be 'float', it should be converted with `df.astype(float)`.

Comment: this was exactly the problem. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My immediate thought is that the round method requires two inputs (number, number of decimals).

Maybe try df = df.apply(lambda x: round(x, 3))`.Then you could also apply a different round to certain columns if you'd like

I tested with this example and it worked:

```
import pandas as pd
#Answering Round question
Curve = [2424.53,1000.467,3000.1234,100.1]
Unnamed_26 = [-.0004567658,-.0005672443,-.00065732114,-.00078695]
Unnamed_27 = [.0012346,.00587261,.00455632,.66778899]
D = {'Curve': Curve,'Unnamed: 26':Unnamed_26,'Unnamed: 27':Unnamed_27}
df = pd.DataFrame(D)
df = df.apply(lambda x: round(x, 3))
df
```